# GATE $2018$ - Probability question : occurrence of green and red faces when die is rolled $7$ times

Tags: probability, expectation

> A six sided unbiased die with four green faces and two red faces is rolled seven times. Which of the following combinations is the likely outcome of the experiment?
>
> (A) Three green faces and four red faces.
>
> (B) Four green faces and three red faces.
>
> (C) Five green faces and two red faces.
>
> (D) Six green faces and one red face.

### [image]

#### My Try:

As probability of occurrence of green face $= 4/6 = 2/3$, and probability of occurrence of red face $= 2/6 = 1/3$.

If the die is rolled $6$ times, then expectation of green and red faces are $4$ and $2$ respectively. But die is rolled $7$ times, so I prefer $5$ green and $2$ red faces as green faces has more probability than red faces.

> Could you please explain it?

Thanks in advance.

---

Comment: I suspect the question intends you to calculate the probability of the event $4G,3R$ in any order for $C$ and similarly for $D$. What you’re interpreting seems considerably different.

Comment: @Macavity, please check my edit.

Comment: If that is the question, as a multiple choice, then the question is wrong. All of the options are possible, some more probable than others, but none are guaranteed to occur / not occur. Do you have a link to the question paper or is this from memory?

Comment: Yes, this question is wrong, Do you mean which is most likely?

Comment: And (a) and (d) are now the same.

Comment: @Macavity, this exam was yesterday, they not published yet. They will published after $11^{th}$ February this year. I posted this based on memory.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks for pointing out, corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability of getting 3 red and 4 green.
$$\Pr(R=3, G=4)=\binom{7}{3}\left(\frac13\right)^3\left(\frac23\right)^4$$
The probability of getting 2 red and 5 green.
$$\Pr(R=2, G=5)=\binom{7}{2}\left(\frac13\right)^2\left(\frac23\right)^5$$

First we compute number of ways in which you can have 3 red and 4 green outcomes in 7 outcomes. This is given by $$\binom73$$now we multiply this with probability that a single outcome may have 3 red and 4 green in a fixed order. $$\left(\frac13\right)^3\left(\frac23\right)^4$$
And we multiply these two. Similarly you can solve for the second one.

For option (C) the probability is $\frac{560}{3^7}$ and for (D) is $\frac{672}{3^7}$ so answer is D

Comment: Thank you for applying Binomial' theorem, but what is answer?

Comment: $\Pr(R=3, G=4)=\binom{7}{3}\left(\frac13\right)^3\left(\frac23\right)^4$

Comment: Do you mean $7C4 > 7C5?$

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

@Piyush's answer is correct, but here's a comment that you can settle the issue without a calculator. We want to see, for example, that the probability of event D is *greater* than the probability of event C. So we want to see, as painlessly as possible, why
$$\binom 75\big(\frac23\big)^5\big(\frac13\big)^2 > \binom 74\big(\frac23\big)^4\big(\frac13\big)^3.$$
Note that $\binom 75 = 21$ and $\binom 74 = 35$, and $\frac{21}{35}<\frac12$.
On the other hand, to go from $\big(\frac23\big)^5\big(\frac13\big)^2$ to $\big(\frac23\big)^4\big(\frac13\big)^3$, we multiply by a factor of $\frac13\cdot\frac32 = \frac12$. Thus, going from the left-hand side to the right hand side we multiply by a factor $<1$. Thus,  the left-hand side is greater.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.